# Implode Taxonomy to hide parents?

Tags: taxonomy

The following code will display the child taxonomy term of the parent only.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, 'propertytype');
 $props = array();
 foreach ($terms as $term) {
 if ($term->parent)
 $props[] = $term->name;
 }
 echo implode(', ', $props);
```

For example: London (Parent), West London (Child) - the above will only echo West London (Child).

However, if there are multiple child levels e.g London (Parent), West London (Child), Chelsea (Grand Child)

This does not work!  I only want to display the last term.

**How would i modify the above to only display the last term even if there is more than one sub level?**

Thanks

Paul

**FINAL CODE USED**

```
   $terms = get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, 'propertytype');
      //die(print_r($terms));
      $props = array();
      foreach ($terms as $term) { 
      $hasChildrenTest = get_term_children($term->ID, 'propertytype');
          if ($term->parent) {
              if (empty($hasChildrenTest) && !is_wp_error($hasChildrenTest)) {
              $props[] = $term->name;
              }
          }
      }
      echo $props[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the resulting term has any children before adding it to the array:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, 'propertytype');
 $props = array();
 foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $hasChildrenTest = get_term_children($term->ID, 'propertyType');
 if ($term->parent) { 
    if (empty($hasChildrenTest) && !is_wp_error($hasChildrenTest)) {
         $props[] = $term->name;
    }
 }
 echo implode(', ', $props);
```

**ps:** the `if($term->parent)` test might become unnecessary after this. Check if you really need it.

**edit:** my mistake -> it should be `empty $hasChildrenTest` instead of `!empty $hasChildrenTest` so if the term has children it doesn't get added.

Comment: Hi Moraleida, Thanks for the response. Unfortunately i am getting - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '('  for line $props[] = $term->name;   any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Comment: my code was missing a pair of parethesis on the empty check, sorry about that. I've updated the example.

Comment: Hi Again, thanks for the response, appreciate it! For some reason when i try the code, it produces another Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE for a later line in the file (<?php endwhile; else: ?>) Not sure why?

Comment: That error means there's something missing before the `endwhile;` statement. Check if you have every parenthesis, brackets and semicolons in place. 

Also consider moving your code to an IDE (like NetBeans or Eclipse) or a better text editor (such as Notepad++). That will help you find out where your syntax errors are.

Comment: Hi Moreleida, Modified the code slightly to get it to work.  <code>$terms = get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, 'propertytype');
              //die(print_r($terms));
              $props = array();
              foreach ($terms as $term) { 
         $hasChildrenTest = get_term_children($term->ID, 'propertytype');
      if ($term->parent) {
          if (empty($hasChildrenTest) && !is_wp_error($hasChildrenTest)) {
               $props[] = $term->name;
          }
      }
              }
              echo $props[0];</code>.  This seems to work : ) Thanks again

Comment: Cool... if it worked for you, then please accept the answer :) -- by the way, use `backticks` instead of <code> to show code in comments. :)

Comment: if($term->parent) is unnecessary because a '0' is reported if there are no parent IDs for the term